# Value of potential difference between two charged plates

Tags: electrostatics, electrons, conservation-laws, voltage, capacitance

I am currently practicing Physics questions in basic electrostatics and I am confused about why my teacher is randomly assigning *V* (potential energy) as 0 in random sides of two parallel plates (where *E* (electric field) is constant).

The question is asking that I find the total energy of a system where an electron enters charged plates through a small hole in the negatively charged plate ($v_i=2.2\times10^6$ m/s) and then exits the system ($v_f=2.7\times10^6$ m/s). (In the question the negatively charged plate is on the right side of the diagram and the positive plate is on the left side of the diagram. [image: The question in question]

My instructor labelled the positive side as *V*=0 and the negative side as *V*=? (since we aren't given the potential energy in the question). I have read up that you can assign either side of the parallel plates as 0, however in this question that does not seem possible. Here are my teacher's calculations:

$$
E_T=E_k+E_p
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{2}mv^2+qV
$$

*qV* was marked as 0 as my teacher denoted *V* as 0 for the positive plate.

$$
=\frac{1}{2}mv^2+0
$$

Given to us on the datasheet is the weight of a single electron: $9.11\times10^{-31}$ kg. Where things start getting confusing is that we used the final velocity value, which is where V was denoted as 0. The point of using final velocity here makes sense, but the same answer is not given when I change V to equal 0 from the negative plate and use the initial velocity in the equation instead. Below is what my teacher did (he used the final velocity value in conjunction with assuming that area has V=0).

$$
=\frac{1}{2}(9.11\times10^{-31})(2.7\times10^6)^2=3.3\times10^{-18}
$$

If we are supposed to be able to interchange which plate V=0 at, then why are there different answers when you perform exactly that manoeuvre?

Comment: The only thing that matters to the electron between the plates is the potential difference between the plates. You are not being asked to calculate the trajectory of the electron outside of that volume.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, but I am concerned with why I cannot label the negative side as V=0 instead of the positive side being labelled that way—if i label the negative side as V=0 it yields the wrong answer.

Comment: When you labelled the negative side as having $V=0$, did you also adjust the positive side accordingly?

Comment: Yes, since a negative side was V = 0, then I labelled the other (positive) side as V = ? since we were not given V in the question. The concern here is that while the idea is that you can label either side as V = 0, I receive an incorrect answer if I do not do what my instructor did, which was label the positive side as 0.

Comment: You can pick any potential for either plate. The only thing that matters is the difference.